# Handlebars without loop and with unnamed json response

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have the following json response: [120,256]

And I have the following html:

```
<div class="content-holder">
    <h1>xxx <small>Moved</small></h1>
    <h2>of yyy Requested</h2>
</div>
```

I need to fill the numbers xxx and yyy with the json response using handlebars but without looping ({{#each .}})

What is the best scenario, taking into consideration that the array isn't named as well?

P.S. the project is Spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can give you is to transform you array in JavaScript into object which is passed to template.

Example:

```
var viewObject = { x: yourArray[0], y: yourArray[1] }
```

and within your view

```
<div class="content-holder">
    <h1>{{x}}<small>Moved</small></h1>
    <h2>of {{y}} Requested</h2>
</div>
```